# django model unit test

Tags: unit-testing, django-models

I'm making unit tests to a model.

This test RUN ok

```
def test_event_creation(self):
    new_user = User.objects.create_user(**self.user_info)
    new_event = Event.objects.create(name="Event test", user=new_user,
        start_date=datetime.date(2011,07,03), end_date=datetime.date(2011,07,10),
        start_time=datetime.time(8,30), end_time=datetime.time(18,00))

    self.assertEqual(Event.objects.count(), 1)
```

The problem is that I need to test the model errors too, for example a invalid name.
In that case the execution of the test show me an error (the error that i'm trying to test)

How i can get that error to compare in a assert and determine if is the error that suppost? to be.

(Maybe i have to use: assertRaisesRegexp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.assertRaises(exception, function, parameters)
```

exception: TypeError, ValueError, http://www.python.org/doc/essays/stdexceptions.html
function: Event.objects.create
parameters: user=new_user, start_date=datetime.date(2011,07,03), etc...

example:

```
def test_event_creation(self):
    new_user = User.objects.create_user(**self.user_info)
    self.assertRaises(TypeError, Event.objects.create,name="Event test", user=new_user,
        start_date=datetime.date(2011,07,03), end_date=datetime.date(2011,07,10),
        start_time=datetime.time(8,30), end_time=datetime.time(18,00))
```